# Java support for Server Name Indication (SNI) in server role?

Tags: java, sni

Java 7 brings [client support for SNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html). Are there known open-source implementations of the SNI server role? Java provides "transparant support" TLS connections (including the handshake), but I need to decouple the handshake process so I can send a certificate back based on the SNI host_name extension.

After failing to find online documentation, I looked in the OpenJDK source code, but there does not seem to be a point where I can monitor the ClientHello message before Java sends the ServerHello message.

Answer (score 4):

I made a quick hack some time ago: https://bitbucket.org/zmarcos/sniserversocket

If you follow the instructions: https://bitbucket.org/zmarcos/sniserversocket/wiki/Home

It will work even on Java EE servers, like Glassfish.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a known open-source implementation for for Java 7, but server SNI support is [coming in Java 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/tl/jdk/rev/3f62cfc4e83d).  If you back-port this to Java 7, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem myself and ended up writing an open source library: [TLS Channel](https://github.com/marianobarrios/tls-channel). The scope of the library is actually bigger: it is a complete abstraction for SSLEngine (which is *seriously* hard to use directly), exposing it as a ByteChannel.

Regarding SNI, the library does the parsing of the first bytes before creating the SSLEngine. The user can then supply a function to the server channel, to select SSLContexts depending on the received domain name.